# Explicitly secure a specific pattern instead of ignoring all non-secured patterns

Tags: spring-security

I have an application where I only need to secure /admin/ pages. All of the other pages have no login, account or other features that require security.

According to other questions and tutorials, I have currently implemented this with explicitly ignoring all paths that don't require security, e.g.

```html
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/js/**");

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**");

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/**");

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/css/**");

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**");
```

This makes the configuration larger and not entirely clear on what you're exactly securing, since it only states the exceptions.

Is there a way to first explicitly disable all security, and then add the patterns for which you want to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring security (even for public static URLs) is generally considered bad practice unless you have explicit reasons to do so. Remember Spring Security also helps with things like [Security HTTP Response Headers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#headers) to ensure your application is secured.

With that in mind, would remove the ignoring configuration you have and simply update your security authorization rules. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

That said if you really need to ignore all requests except those that start with admin, you can easily perform this with a regular expression:

```
web
    .ignoring()
        .regexMatchers("^(?!/admin/).*");
```

You can also inject custom matcher implementations. Spring Security even provides the ones below out of the box:

```
RequestMatcher adminRequests = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**");
RequestMatcher notAdminRequests = new NegatedRequestMatcher(adminRequests);
web
    .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(notAdminRequests);
```