# Ignoring path in WebSecurity config in Spring

Tags: java, spring, websecurity

I have the configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/base/**");
}
```

And I want to include for view from all paths just this path `/base/includepath`.

How I can do it?

Comment: you config is proper and it contains your requirement !! what is problem?

Comment: I want to not ignoring the path `/base/includepath`. Now this configuration ignoring all paths over `/base/`.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328120/explicitly-secure-a-specific-pattern-instead-of-ignoring-all-non-secured-pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude url from authentication(like /base/includepath) you just need to act like below:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/base/includepath");
}
```

I hope this was what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I want to exclude all others paths, less `/base/includepath`.